# React Re-Render and update issue

Tags: reactjs

1. Suppose I have 10k of record and whenever I am trying to update state using setState every time component  is re-render but I want after all changes on state component should render once only. 
   example :-

```js
constructor(){
     this.state={
        employeeList:[{name:a},{name:b},{name:c},{name:d},{name:e}.....]
     }
 }
```

I want to update `a,b,c,d,e`  to `1 ,2 ,3 ,4,5` by using `this.setState()` but after update all value i need to re-render component not after update one by one.

Please help me.

Comment: how did you use setstate? 
you can copy the  employeeList  from state to a newEmployeeList var, update it and after all re setState({ employeeList: newEmployeeList })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this:

- Use the 'shouldComponentUpdate' and decide in it whether to render.
- Use a pure component.

## Using 'shouldComponentUpdate'

The following text is copied from "[How does React decide to re-render a component?](http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/)":

"By default,  shouldComponentUpdate returns true. That’s what causes a component to render everytime there is a state change. However, you can overwrite shouldComponentUpdate to give it more “smarts” if you need the performance boost. Instead of letting React re-render all the time, you can tell React when you don’t want to trigger a re-render."

## Use a pure component

The following text is copied from "[Why and How to Use PureComponent in React.js](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html)": "PureComponent changes the life-cycle method shouldComponentUpdate and adds some logic to automatically check whether a re-render is required for the component. This allows a PureComponent to call method render only if it detects changes in state or props."

Comment: inside of shouldComponentUpdate call setState . But I tried to use shouldComponentUpdate  but it's also re-render the component every time

Comment: Read http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/. It explains how to do it, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your state updates differently

Instead of updating state separately for each value, you would update it once like

```
update() {
   const newValues = [1,2,3,4,5];
   const newEmployeeList = this.state.employeeList.map((obj, index) => {
      return {...obj, name: newValues[index]};
   })
   this.setState({employeeList: newEmployeeList})
}
```